# Doing two Bachelors before Masters degree?

Tags: masters, germany, bachelor, second-degree

I currently study for my B.Sc. in Media IT. I easily could finish a second Bachelor if I do one more semester. I want to do master's degree in Media IT afterwards.

I'm already 23 and in the third semester, since I finished an apprenticeship as a software developer before. Is it useful to start my master's with 26 and probably finish it when I'm ~28?

Comment: If 1 more semester would qualify you for a second Bachelor's, then presumably you'd qualify for a minor if you don't do that second semester?

Comment: Also, are you primarily asking about if you should spend an extra semester to do a second Bachelor's, or are you asking if you should do the Master's?  Or, are you pointing out that you have 4 different choices (1BS; 2BS; 1BS+MS; 2BS+MS) and asking which of the 4 choices you should do?

Comment: I wanted to ask, if a second Bachelor in 7 semesters instead one in 6 semesters is useful, before doing a Masters. So 1BS+MS in ~8 semesters or 2BS+MS in ~9 semesters?

Answer (score 1):

Giving a perfect advice is not possible, but consider:
Those skills are searched for, a semester more could be explained. You should bevable to do so, ideally by being able to show your learnings applied. Any projects in parallel? When asked, mention them. Show why a good knowledge plus experience makes you different.
I ended my university diploma in CS when i was 27, and added a PhD afterwards. I never regretted learning more by drilling some deeper holes than usual. And from the afterwards jobs, I got really well paid.

Answer (score 1):

When I was an employer of hundreds of highly educated people I drew a distinction between those with the highest technical skills and those who could show, possibly, but not necessarily, through having acquired qualifications, that they could apply themselves to new challenges. I was not particularly impressed by a long string of university degrees unless I could fit the holder into one of those two categories.

You have to decide how you are to sell yourself to future employers. They will mostly be interested in what you can do for them. Your degrees will help them place you, but you have to decide first how you want to place yourself. 28 years is not all that old if you have something to offer in the future, but do bear in mind that by definition a university degree is about what you have done in the past. It is evidence, but not proof.

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward: nobody cares about your undergrad degrees when you're being judged at the level of graduate degrees or against others with experience. In fact, it can give a harmful image since it took you two tries at the "trivial" level before moving to the masters and PhD level of "professional maturity".

That's a very harsh way of saying it, but I think undergrads always overestimate the value of their current experience (I did this too). Yes, you're learning a lot in a classroom, but you're not "doing anything". If someone asks you to "show me who you are", what would you point to? A GPA and some final reports? At some point you need to flip the switch and take ownership of your career: switch from being a learner to a creator. It doesn't matter how. Graduate level work is based around starting to do research: writing essays and sharing them with the world in order to become well known as the expert in a subject. Industry jobs have you applying your skills on the market. You might not feel like you know enough (that's just [imposter syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)), but you'll realize how ready you are for the world at 24 with an undergrad degree when you start taking on your own projects. Once you've learned enough, you shouldn't be paying people to do work: they should be paying you.